Generate order link
I'm trying to generate a link to the order that is displayed on a commerce checkout pane.
$order_link = $this->order->toLink($this->order->getOrderNumber());
$link = $order_link->toString();

Unfortunately, this always returns links whose relative path is like /admin/commerce/orders/5, for every user.
How can I get a link that points to /user/2/orders/5, for example?
This code worked fine, previously. After upgrading to Drupal 10.3 and the latest commerce version, it started to give link to the admin pages.
